# Why does this Python code just print one of the variables over and over again?

Tags: python

I am writing some code, which involves multiplying a variable with a number. This is the code that seems to be breaking:

```
print (var2)
var1 = var2 * 1050
print(var1)
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

When i run the script, say var2 is 3, it should be returning 
    3
    3150
but instead it returns:

```
3
333333333333333333333333333333333..... you get the idea.
```

Comment: @Transformer: Be careful not to change the content of a question when editing. There is a big difference between `input` and `raw_input`, and I would not change this without asking the OP first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `var2` is a string. Appliying `*N` to a string has the effect of returning a string with `N` repetitions of the original. For example

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> s * 3
'123123123'
```

You need to convert `var2` to a numerical type, presumably an integer. For example,

```
>>> int(s) * 3
369
```